# Plot Points on Jvector Map based on JSON data

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, jvectormap

I Have a JSON Data which I fetched from the database using Mysql.
The JSON is given Below :

```
[
    {
        "Country":"Australia",
        "persons":"5"
    },
    {
        "Country":"Spain",
        "persons":"2"
    },
    {
        "Country":"India",
        "persons":"8"
    },
    {
        "Country":"Mexico",
        "persons":"4"
    },
    {
        "Country":"United States",
        "persons":"4"
    }
]
```

What I Want is that, How Can I Color the Specific region in the Jvector Map also showing the no. of Counts that I am having.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: I don't have the Idea how to show the Data using PHP .  Please if you have any idea . Please Share with me.

Comment: Please tell me is it Possible or NOT ? @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Before posting a question, you should have done the proper research and made attempts to solve your issue yourself. Then, if you get stuck on something _specific_ with your existing code, come back and show us your attempt. Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)